# How to add more files at once using FS.Collection in Meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm using FS.Collection package to insert and store Images. The problem is I can't submit more files than one per once. How to enable it ? Here is my insert function :

```js
// Upload images 
'change #exampleInput':function(event, template){
  // Get Session with 4 words password
  var fourWords = Session.get("fourWords");
  var file = $('#exampleInput').get(0).files[0] //Some jQuery to get the value.

  fsFile = new FS.File(file);
  // Store 4 words password in metadata
  fsFile.metadata = {
    fourWords:fourWords,
  } 
  // Insert into Image Collection
  Images.insert(fsFile,function(err,result){
    if(!err){
      console.log(result)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but a for loop adding one at a time doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
// Upload images 
'change #exampleInput':function(event, template){
  // Get Session with 4 words password
  var fourWords = Session.get("fourWords");
  FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
    file = $('#exampleInput').get(0).files[0], // or use event.target.files;
    fsFile = new FS.File(file);
    fsFile.metadata = {
        fourWords:fourWords,
      }  
    Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
    });
 });
}
```

This work for me but i dont like to use to use multiple file upload, there is a commong issue when you upload more than 10-15 images into the collection, a [lag issue](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/issues/352).

Comment: thanks again Ethaan, you are right as usual, not gonna use it after all, besides i don't know why, but it doesn't work on mobile

Comment: check if the event is getting fired, put a `console.log("event fired on mobile")`